# Way to not include something in regex capture group

Tags: c#, regex

Given:

```
var input = "test <123>";

Regex.Matches(input, "<.*?>");
```

Result:

```
<123>
```

Gives me the result I want but includes the angle brackets. Which is ok because I can easily do a search and replace. I was just wondering if there was a way to include that in the expression?

Comment: Did you try `"<(.*?)>"` and retrive the `Group`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a *capturing group*:

```
var input = "test <123>";
var results = Regex.Matches(input, "<(.*?)>")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

The `m.Groups[1].Value` lets you get the capturing group #1 value.

And a better, more efficient regex can be `<([^>]*)>` (it matches `<`, then matches and *captures* into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `>` and then just matches `>`). See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3C%28%5B%5E%3E%5D*%29%3E&i=test%20%3C123%3E):

[image]